# How to invoke mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

mapStateToProps returns an object with 2 keys, **provider** & **plan**.
The provider's value cannot be resolved until the **plan** is already a property of props. **provider** depends on the plan's property (plan.provider).

My idea was, the first time mapStateToProps gets invoked, it will return the following:

(And that is indeed what happens)

```
{
  plan: [Object],
  provider: undefined
}
```

Now that the **plan** is resolved and mapped to props I need the mapStateToProps to get invoked once again so that the **provider** can resolve aswell. The second time mapStateToProps should return:

```
{
  plan: [Object],
  provider: [Object]
}
```

Is this the right way to deal with a situation like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's a perfectly reasonable approach.  Assuming that a second action is dispatched which adds the appropriate data to the store, `mapState` will re-run and return the updated values, and the component will re-render.

Your React component should be written so that it can safely handle the missing `provider` prop, such as checking to see if it exists and returning a "loading..." component if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is a good way to solve this. I believe if you have plan as a promise or an async action that you have to wait for before updating provider value, you need to do it Redux Middleware.Most reliable of them in my opinion is Thunk, which allows you to write async code in actions and then when the Promise resolves, you can update `provider` in your state.

To avoid `undefined` provider value at the UI, use `defaultProps` which will help you to avoid issues because of `undefined` provider.

I hope that helps.